# React: onClick on table data (button) - get whole data related to row which are generated using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are many queries related to get table row data,i tried all the ways.Help me to find where i'm doing wrong.

On clicking on the choose button, i have to get the array related to that row.

How to get Row related data (array)?

My code as follows:

in State:

```
 this.state = {
      demo: [
        {
          no: 1,
          name: "test",
          cityname: "hyd",
          cityname1: "bng",
          basec: 10,
          other: "addtnal data",
        },
        {
          no: 2,
          name: "test2",
          cityname: "del",
          cityname1: "krnt",
          basec: 20,
          other: "addtnal data",
        },
      ]}
```

My table in jsx:

```
<Table className={classNames(classes.table)}>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell padding="default">no</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">name</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">cityname</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">cityname1</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="right">basec</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {this.state.demo.map((item) => [
                  <TableRow key={item.no}>
                    <TableCell padding="default">{item.no}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{item.name}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{item.cityname}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{item.cityname1}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">{item.basec}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">
                      <Button
                        color="secondary"
                        data-item={item}
                        onClick={this.handleChoosedRow}
                      >
                        Choose
                      </Button>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>,
                ])}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
```

Handle choose row:

```
handleChoosedRow = (e) => {
    const row = e.target.getAttribute("data-item");
    console.log("choosed flight", row);
  };
```

Expected output:

Foe example, OnClicking, on the 1st row (index[0]) the choosed date will be

```
  {
          no: 1,
          name: "test",
          cityname: "hyd",
          cityname1: "bng",
          basec: 10,
          other: "addtnal data",
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: on click on choose , i unable to get related row data.

Comment: But it should not be able to render row data since there may be a problem in your map function ```this.state.demo.map((item) => [//code]```. It should be ```this.state.demo.map((item) => (//code)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `onClick` event like,

`onClick={() => this.handleChoosedRow(item)}`

Here `item` is your expected result which comes under map method and you can directly pass it down to `handleChoosedRow`..

Then you can get the selected row in `handleChoosedRow` function like,

```
handleChoosedRow = (row) => {
  console.log("choosed flight", row);
};
```

**Table:**

```
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell padding="default">no</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">name</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">cityname</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">cityname1</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">basec</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {this.state.demo.map((item) => [
              <TableRow key={item.no}>
                <TableCell padding="default">{item.no}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{item.name}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{item.cityname}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{item.cityname1}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{item.basec}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">
                  <Button
                    color="secondary"
                    data-item={item}
                    onClick={() => this.handleChoosedRow(item)}
                  >
                    Choose
                  </Button>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>,
            ])}
          </TableBody>
    </Table>
```

**Function:**

```
handleChoosedRow = (row) => {
  console.log("choosed flight", row);
};
```

> [**Working Codesandbox here..**](https://codesandbox.io/s/2-react-table-jq5jz)